# Is $A$ necessarily a compact set or a connected set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $A\subset \mathbb R$ is defined by :

> $A=\{y\in \mathbb R:y=\lim f(x_n),$ for some sequence $x_n\to \infty\}$

Is $A$ necessarily  a compact set or a connected set?

**My try**:

Since $f$ is continuous and $x_n\to \infty$ so either $f(x_n)\to \infty $ or $f(x_n)\to -\infty$ .Hence $A$ is finite and compact but the answer is given to be connected. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is continuous. What is its limit as $x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: $x_n\rightarrow\infty$ doesn't imply $f(x_n)\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Alan's answer: to show that it is connected, prove that it is an interval.

Let $x,y \in A$ with $x \le y$, and let $z \in [x,y]$. Then, $\exists 0\le a \le 1$, such that $z = ax + (1-a)y$. Let $(x_n)$ be the one associated to $x$ and $(y_n)$ be that associated to $y$.

Now put $u_n = af(x_n) +(1-a)f(y_n)$. Then, by IVT, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\exists z_n \in [x_n, y_n]$ or $[y_n, x_n]$ such that $u_n = f(z_n)$.

Therefore, $z_n \to \infty$ and $f(z_n) \to z$, so $z \in A$.

Answer (score 2):

To show that it is not compact,  consider a continuous function that is piecewise linear,  connecting (0,0), (1,1), (2,-1), (3,-2), (4,-2),  etc....so it is oscillating higher and higher over time.  (You can have the function be identically equal to 0 in the negatives).

Then your set $A$ will be all real numbers!   Because for any real number,  after you get past twice that number,  every interval of length 2 contains a point with that value, so you have a constant sequence of $x_n$ where the $y_n$ hits that y.

Comment: A simple function such as $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ would also work, but be a little less messy.